# SQLiteException syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to crete a SQLite database in an android application in a SQLiteOpenHelper subclass and I am getting the following error:

```
.SQLiteException: near "playlist": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE playlist(
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
playlist_name TEXT,
sound_id Integer,
FOREIGN KEY (sound_id) REFERENCES sound(_ID)
);
```

Here is my relevant code starting with the `String` constants with the SQL code used to create my databse:

```
public static final String CREATE_PLAYLIST_TABLE = "CREATE playlist(\n" +
        "   _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
        "   playlist_name TEXT,\n" +
        "   sound_id Integer,\n" +
        "   FOREIGN KEY (sound_id) REFERENCES sound(_ID)\n" +
        ");";

public static final String CREATE_SOUND_TABLE = "CREATE sound(\n" +
        "   _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
        "   volume REAL,\n" +
        "   rate REAL,\n" +
        "   FOREIGN KEY (sound_file) REFERENCES sound_file(_ID)\n" +
        ");";

public static final String CREATE_SOUND_FILE_TABLE = "CREATE sound_file(\n" +
        "   _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
        "   sound_name TEXT,\n" +
        "   is_rate_editing_enabled REAL,\n" +
        "   url TEXT\n" +
        ");";
```

And here is the `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` method:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate database called");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYLIST_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SOUND_FILE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SOUND_TABLE);
}
```

Any ideas as far as what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the keyword `TABLE`:

```
"CREATE TABLE playlist (" +
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
    "playlist_name TEXT, " +
    "sound_id INTEGER, " +
    "FOREIGN KEY (sound_id) REFERENCES sound(_ID))";
```

Also for the other 2 tables.

The **;** is simply useless.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that! Thanks.